# Library UI for android

Tags: android-widget, android

Question: I want to make a wooden shelf which can hold magazine. I am going with the list view having wooden shelf as background image. I have used customized list with 3 image view in portrait mode and 4 image view in landscape mode.Now how can i add dynamically thumbnail of magazines and how can i uniquely detect the item?
I thought this way to design the shelf as it would be simple way, i am not sure. Suggest me.

Comment: for these questions, you need to learn about Adapter in list view http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: The above link is really very helpful for list view. Exploring this,hope it could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/) by Romain Guy, more specifically [this](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/view/ShelvesView.java). Here he has used gridview with image as background. 
Hope it helps.